# Passing objects through controllers in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, web, controllers

I am very puzzled.. 
I am running Symfony2.3.

I have a controller that forwards to a separate controller if a form is submitted.

```
   if ($form->isValid()) {
         $response = $this->forward('MusicMBundle:Song:addTrackToSong', array(
            'Track'=>$Track,
            ));
         return $response;
   }
```

However, as can be seen, the Track parameter is passed through this forward to the following (simplified) controller, with another form.

```
    public function addTrackToSongAction(Request $request, $Track){
          if ($form->isValid()) {   
                //LOGIC
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MusicMBundle_homepage'));
          }
          return $this->render('MusicMBundle:Song:addtracktosong.html.twig', array(
               'Track' => $Track, 'form' => $form->createView(),
          ));
```

If I var_dump($Track) anywhere in the function, it exists and is exactly what I want it to be.

However, when the second form is submitted, symfony2 throws the following error:

```
Controller "Music\MBundle\Controller\SongController::addTrackToSongAction()" requires 
that you provide a value for the "$Track" argument (because there is no default value 
or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

Quite frankly I am puzzled. I have access to everything I need, but symfony is getting very angry at me.  The problem could be in my forwarding strategy I suppose?

Here is my routing file if the problem could be there:

```
MusicMBundle_Song_addTrackToSong:
pattern: /addTrackToSong
defaults: { _controller: MusicMBundle:Song:addTrackToSong }
requirements:
   _method: GET|POST
```

I am a beginner with the framework and I just don't know where to start and can't find anything on it.

If I can provide any other info let me know.

Thanks so much!

Comment: did you try to remove the Request parameter and use `$this->getRequest()` instead

Comment: Either you are pointing to the wrong route (forwarded route) or $Track should be nullable `public function addTrackToSongAction(Request $request, $Track = null)` but I vote for the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route might be incorrect, because it has no parameters. You can try adding a parameter for Track in your route, by changing your pattern in your routing file from this:

```
pattern: /addTrackToSong
```

to this:

```
pattern: /addTrackToSong/{Track}
```

If you visit the url */addTrackToSong/yourTrackValue*, $Track in *SongController::addTrackToSongAction* method will equal **yourTrackValue**.

Another way to resolve the problem, would be by setting a default value for $Track in your action method.

```
public function addTrackToSongAction(Request $request, $Track = null) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So I have attempted routing with parameters, however Track is actually an object, passed as an array with about 10 values.  When I add the null parameter, null is passed through rather than the track passed in itself.  I think I will try using the track id and then getting it from the entity manager on the next page.  Not exactly efficient but I'm still puzzled.  Thanks again though!

Comment: Is the track object an entity? In this case, just pass the ID of the Track entity as an argument, and load the whole object again when needed, using that ID.

Comment: Perfect! You responded before I even finished updating my post. Sounds like it should be a good plan. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I think it should. After all, that's why identifiers are for, isn't it? ;) If you're still having issues, just let us know :)

Comment: well what if he does not want the trackid to be available in the URL? this could be a security breach. Say you have only access to one trackid. Well with this pattern in the URL, you can easily enter whatever you want. you would have to implement this somehow different, which sucks. 
So there is NO way to pass an object to the controller?

Comment: Don't know, don't think you can pass objects to a url. It always ends up as string or int. But, let's say you generate a hashed string for identifying a track, you can *remove the `Track` class from the controller action and apply your own logic* to fetch the correct objects.  You can also create your own `ParamConverter` class to handle it for you.  I made a little [gist demonstration](https://gist.github.com/UrGuardian4ngel/a2d3bf9341492cce1b08).

Answer (score -1):

One simple and easy solution is to serialize and deserialize (field tested). It actually converts any object (also arrays) into strings and back, so you can use it in URLs.

Encoding an object to string:

```
    $track_object_as_string = urlencode(base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($Track))));
```

Decoding a string into an object:

```
    $Track = urldecode(unserialize(gzuncompress(base64_decode($track_object_as_string)));
```

Comment: This is just useless, because URL has length limitations, never use this.

Comment: I beg to differ, if you have short enough objects. And URL can be 2000 characters long, which is good enough for a pretty long zipped object.

But I would not encourage it, it is considered more as a hack than a good practice.